# concat multiple tables in sql when no relationships in between them

Tags: sql, join

When I execute below query:

```
SELECT abc.Id FROM dbo.ABC abc
```

[image]

When I execute below another query:

```
SELECT top 1 def.ProductGroupId, def.TextPrompt, def.IsRequired FROM dbo.DEF def
```

[image]

Now here what I want as a result is:

[image]

There is no relationship in above two tables. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an explicit `cross join`:

```
SELECT abc.id, def.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 def.ProductGroupId, def.TextPrompt, def.IsRequired
      FROM dbo.DEF def
     ) def CROSS JOIN
     dbo.ABC;
```

Note:  In general, you should not use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`.  You will be getting an indeterminate row from `def`, a row that might change each time you run the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **self join** to achieve this:

```
SELECT abc.id, def.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 def.ProductGroupId, def.TextPrompt, def.IsRequired
      FROM dbo.DEF def
     ) def , dbo.ABC abc
```